# Cannot ssh on system startup

Tags: ssh, sshd

I am having an issue where I can ssh into the machine (Linux Mint) perfectly fine using Pub-key authentication, but whenever I restart the machine Permission denied (publickey) This issue is resolved whenever I manually login at the physical machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are [the contents of `auth.log`](https://hastebin.com/agukofejeq.coffeescript):

```
Sep  4 19:03:07 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: New seat seat0.
Sep  4 19:03:07 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (Power Button)
Sep  4 19:03:07 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Sep  4 19:03:07 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Lid Switch)
Sep  4 19:03:07 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
Sep  4 19:03:07 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Sep  4 19:03:15 mint-1 sshd[977]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep  4 19:03:15 mint-1 sshd[977]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep  4 19:03:15 mint-1 CRON[895]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  4 19:03:16 mint-1 CRON[895]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep  4 19:03:22 mint-1 sshd[977]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Sep  4 19:03:22 mint-1 sshd[977]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep  4 19:03:22 mint-1 sshd[977]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep  4 19:03:24 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm-greeter:setcred): (null): pam_sm_setcred
Sep  4 19:03:24 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:setcred): (null): pam_sm_setcred
Sep  4 19:03:24 mint-1 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Sep  4 19:03:24 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
Sep  4 19:03:24 mint-1 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Sep  4 19:03:25 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm-greeter:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
Sep  4 19:03:25 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm-greeter:session): pam_kwallet: open_session called without kwallet_key
Sep  4 19:03:25 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
Sep  4 19:03:25 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): pam_kwallet5: open_session called without kwallet5_key
Sep  4 19:03:33 mint-1 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "my_user"
Sep  4 19:03:36 mint-1 sshd[1200]: Connection from 10.0.0.16 port 3739 on 10.0.0.161 port 22
Sep  4 19:03:36 mint-1 sshd[1200]: Failed publickey for my_user from 10.0.0.16 port 3739 ssh2: RSA SHA256:12345dhu67789
Sep  4 19:03:36 mint-1 sshd[1200]: error: Received disconnect from 10.0.0.16 port 3739:14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
Sep  4 19:03:36 mint-1 sshd[1200]: Disconnected from authenticating user my_user 10.0.0.16 port 3739 [preauth]
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:auth): (null): pam_sm_authenticate
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:auth): pam_kwallet: Couldn't create salt file
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:auth): pam_kwallet: Fail into creating the hash
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:auth): (null): pam_sm_authenticate
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:auth): pam_kwallet5: Couldn't create salt file
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:auth): pam_kwallet5: Fail into creating the hash
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:setcred): pam_kwallet: pam_sm_setcred
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: Removed session c1.
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user my_user by (uid=0)
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 systemd-logind[802]: New session c2 of user my_user.
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user my_user by (uid=0)
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet: pam_sm_open_session
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet: open_session called without kwallet_key
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_open_session
Sep  4 19:03:49 mint-1 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet5: open_session called without kwallet5_key
Sep  4 19:04:01 mint-1 polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.59 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
```

Comment: Do you have per-user encrypted homedirs enabled? In that case, your public key for login can't be in your home directory, because it's still encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

My Home directory was encrypted which causes my ssh keys to become inaccessible.